# Why is my delegate never called?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am trying to make my iPhone 7 Plus into an iBeacon for testing purposes

I am using the code below but my delegate is never called so it does not start the advertising

```
- (IBAction)adminViewBeaconSwitchToggled:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *tillUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(_adminViewBeaconSwitch.isOn) {
        [tillUserDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"beaconIsOn"];
        if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"iBeacon Mode: ON");

            NSUUID *proximityUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"39876A4B-43B2-4BE8-9A9C-41BAE913D56A"];

            CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[ CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:proximityUUID identifier:@"me.netwizards.office"];

            _beaconPeripheralData = [beaconRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:nil];

            _peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:nil queue:nil];

            //[peripheralManager startAdvertising:beaconPeripheralData];
        }
    } else {
        [tillUserDefaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"beaconIsOn"];
        if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"iBeacon Mode: OFF");
        }
    }
}

- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
    NSLog(@"iBeacon update state was triggered");

    switch (peripheral.state) {
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
            NSLog(@"Powered on");
            [peripheral startAdvertising:_beaconPeripheralData];
            break;
        case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
            NSLog(@"Powered Off");
            [peripheral stopAdvertising];
            break;
        case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
            NSLog(@"Device not supported");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I make it start to actually advertise and make sure the delegate is called?

Comment: `[[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:nil queue:nil]` here in place of nil you should pass `initWithDelegate:self`

Comment: that results in the following warning /Users/mdouhan/Documents/dev/NWMobileTill/NWMobileTill/AdminView.m:110:80: Sending 'AdminView *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<CBPeripheralManagerDelegate> _Nullable'

Comment: Have you defined that delegate in your class like this `ClassName <CBPeripheralManagerDelegate>`

Comment: Ahh I had not, this works great with that change please make an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here while initializing the object of `CBPeripheralManager`

```
_peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:nil queue:nil];
```

you are passing the delegate as `nil`, which you should pass as `self`.

So your updated code should be

```
_peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

Also, define the delegate `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` in your class.